# Add a 1/0 Counting Column to SQL server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I need to publish several SQL-server tables in our BI environment, the one thing I need to add is a count of distinct values to use as occurences in the BI environment.

This will make it much more usable to look for distinct counts for my end-users. I can do this easily with an excel macro but now have much larger data-sets that I do not want to take out of SQL-server.

I basically need to add columns that count the distinct values of another column as 1 so the sum of this column would be the total number of distinct values in the original column.

What I have is this:

```
COM-ID  /  PERSON ID
C001      P001
C001      P002
C002      P001
C002      P003
C003      P004
```

What I need is this:

```
COM-ID  /  PERSON ID / COM-COUNT / PER-COUNT
C001      P001       1          1
C001      P002       0          1
C002      P001       1          1
C002      P003       0          1
C003      P004       1          0
```

Comment: If `COM-ID` and `PERSON ID` are (when together) unique, have you considered using a GROUP BY? you could then do either a `COUNT` or if it is just `1` oe `0` returned something along the lines of `CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT [COM-ID]) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` I've not put this as an answer as I'm not completely certain what you need.

Comment: Yes, in this example the combination of both those ID's are unique, but there are other data points that i need to count in the same way like email addresses or job functions.